# Is the question on cooking turning food unsafe clear enough?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have a recent question, [Is anything made less safe by cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/83832/is-anything-made-less-safe-by-cooking). I liked it at first, thinking it might bring to light interesting edge cases.

However, seeing the comments and answers, I am very worried about the question. It seems that everybody has a different interpretation of what consitutes "safe", what constitutes "cooking" and what constitutes "turn unsafe".

Is there any sense to leave the question open as it currently is? Does it help to bring information to people, or does it just cause confusion?

If the answer is "no", what do we do about it - edit, or close? And if edit, what should be contained in this edit?

Answer (score 1):

Phrase suggestion:

"made less safe" -> "caused to fail an accepted food safety standard that it did not fail in its raw state, AND/OR turned into a food considered perishable under such standards when it was not considered perishable in its raw state."

The scope of "cooking" remains to be solved - if you include "distillation", that would add a few more valid cases (highly concentrated alcohol or acetic acid isn't that safe to have neat ;) ).